# Setting ids in has_many relationship between three models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

A user can create a post. Posts have comments. A comment must belong to both a user and a post, however not necessarily the user who created the post. Is the following the best way to model this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

If so, what is the best practice for ensuring:

1. `user.comments.new` cannot be called. I want all new posts to be created using the `post` they are associated with.
2. The `id` of the user creating the comment is properly set when calling `post.comments.new`

Otherwise, what is a better way to model this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are fine.

To set the author of the comment, you'd have to do that in your controller:

```
@comment = post.comments.new do |c|
    c.user = current_user
end
```

Just don't use `user.comments.new`. Why do you want to make it impossible to use it?

Comment: Thanks for verifying the model structure. I was planning to do something like that in my controller but wanted to make sure it was considered the "rails way" etc. etc. I don't need to make it impossible to call user.comments.new but wanted to make sure that leaving it available (i.e not monkey patching to make it worthless) was considered alright. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, leaving it is perfectly fine. Also, are you using `user.comments.new` in the new action or in the create action? In general, you should use `build` instead of `new` when building the object from an association. In recent rails versions, both work, but `build` also add the object to the comments collection of the post and keeps it in memory. Not sure about all the details, you can search for the difference on google and decide yourself ;)

Comment: Right - I am aware of the difference between <code>new</code> and <code>build</code> as it relates to relationships - thanks again!